# Recursive procedure in MIPS - stack?

Tags: recursion, stack, mips

I have to create a procedure `eval_expr` in MIPS. Basically, it performs basic operations like a calculator, so  if an argument in address `$a0` is positive then it stores a number, if it is negative, the operation is performed and it can be either:

- `-80`, then addition is performed
- `-60`, then subtraction is performed
- `-40`, then we shift right
- `-20`, then we shift left

`$a0 + 4` stores the address of left sub-expression

`$a0 + 8` stores the address of right sub-expression

Using pseudo-code, we can write this procedure as:

```
int eval_expr (expr e) {
    if (is_number(e)) {
        return e.op;
    }
    else {
        if (e == -80)
            return eval_expr(e.left) + eval_expr(e. right);
        if (e == -60)
            return eval_expr(e.left) - eval_expr(e.right);
        if (e == -40)
            return eval_expr(e.left) >> eval_expr(e.right);
        if (e == -20)
            return eval_expr(e.left) << eval_expr(e.right);
        }
}
```

Here's the code I got so far:

```
eval_expr:
#stack frame 
addi $sp $sp -24
sw $ra 4($sp)
sw $fp 8($sp)
addiu $fp $sp 20

#if positive
lw $t1 ($a0)
slti $t0 $t1 0
bne $t0 $zero else
add $v0 $t1 $zero
j destack

#if negative
else:
addi $t3 $zero -20 
addi $t4 $zero -40
addi $t5 $zero -60
addi $t6 $zero -80

beq $a0 $t3 sl
beq $a0 $t4 sr
beq $a0 $t5 subs
beq $a0 $t6 addit

sl:
sw $a0 ($sp)
lw $a0 4($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $a0 ($sp)
sw $v0 12($sp)
lw $a0 8($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $t0 12($sp)
sllv $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack

sr:
sw $a0 ($sp)
lw $a0 4($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $a0 ($sp)
sw $v0 12($sp)
lw $a0 8($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $t0 12($sp)
srlv $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack

subs:
sw $a0 ($sp)
lw $a0 4($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $a0 ($sp)
sw $v0 12($sp)
lw $a0 8($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $t0 12($sp)
sub $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack

addit:
sw $a0 ($sp)
lw $a0 4($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $a0 ($sp)
sw $v0 12($sp)
lw $a0 8($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $t0 12($sp)
add $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack

#destacking
destack:
lw $a0 ($sp)
lw $ra 4($sp)
lw $fp 8($sp)
addi $sp $sp 24
jr $ra
```

Unfortunately it only works if the operation performed is shifting left. I think this is because this part of the code is not jumping anywhere (which indicated some sort of problem with stack?), therefore always shifting left is performed.

```
beq $a0 $t3 sl
beq $a0 $t4 sr
beq $a0 $t5 subs
beq $a0 $t6 addit
```

Here are all the tests I ran:

```
Evaluate : (2<<2)
** Test passed **  Expected : 8 Received : 8

Evaluate : (1<<(2+(3-4)))
!! TEST FAILED !!  Expected : 2 Received : 1

Evaluate : (((2<<2)+(2<<2))<<((2<<2)+(2<<2)))
!! TEST FAILED !!  Expected : 1048576 Received : 2048

Evaluate : ((((1<<(2+(3-4)))<<3)-4)-(((2<<2)+(2<<2))<<((2<<2)+(2<<2))))
!! TEST FAILED !!  Expected : -1048564 Received : 128

Evaluate : (((((1<<(2+(3-4)))<<3)-4)-(((2<<2)+(2<<2))<<((2<<2)+(2<<2))))>>5)
!! TEST FAILED !!  Expected : -32768 Received : 4096

Evaluate : (((1+2)+((1<<(2+(3-4)))<<3))-(((((1<<(2+(3-4)))<<3)-4)-(((2<<2)+(2<<2))<<((2<<2)+(2<<2))))>>5))
!! TEST FAILED !!  Expected : 32787 Received : 1024
```

Comment: Simulators like SPIM and MARS lets you step through your code and set breakpoints at locations of particular interest. That should allow you to find where the behavior of your function starts to deviate from what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

All right, if anyone is interested in answer - I was loading only an address, not an actual value (from register $a0). Here's the corrected version of the code:

```
    eval_expr:
#stack frame
addi $sp $sp -24
sw $ra 4($sp)
sw $fp 8($sp)
addiu $fp $sp 20

#if positive
lw $t1 ($a0)
slti $t0 $t1 0
bne $t0 $zero else
add $v0 $t1 $zero
j destack

#if negative
else:
sw $a0 16($sp)
lw $a0 4($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $a0 16($sp)
sw $v0 20($sp)
lw $a0 8($a0)
jal eval_expr
lw $t0 20($sp)
lw $a0 16($sp)
add $t1 $a0 $zero
lw $a0 ($a0) 
addi $t3 $zero -20
beq $a0 $t3 sl
addi $t3 $zero -40
beq $a0 $t3 sr
addi $t3 $zero -60
beq $a0 $t3 subs
addi $t3 $zero -80
beq $a0 $t3 addit


#operations

sl:
sllv $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack
sr:
srav $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack
addit:
add $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack
subs:

sub $v0 $t0 $v0
j destack

#destacking
destack:
lw $a0 ($sp)
lw $ra 4($sp)
lw $fp 8($sp)
addi $sp $sp 24
jr $ra
```